# Why Is This Element's Z-Index staying set to auto when I specify 2

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails application where I need to have a button with a z-index of 2 to be on top of another element. I set that by the button's ID with this SCSS

```
#hireButton {
    z-index: 2 !important;
}
```

However, when I open the web page, the button is hidden behind the element that it is on top of. When I inspect the button, I find Chrome telling me that my button's Z-index is still auto but 2 is hidden underneath.

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Z-index won't take effect unless the element has a `position` value of anything **other** than `static`,

Comment: Seems like the ruby-on-rails tag here is misleading?